# Python: Tornado and persistent database connection

Tags: python, database, asynchronous, tornado

I am reading [tornado documentation](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.initialize). I would like to have persistent connection(connection is up during application lifetime) to DB and return data from DB asynchronously. Where is the best place of doing this?

- `def initialize` ?
- handler's `__init__` method?
- `def prepare`?
- or other place?

Could you provide some examples?

Comment: Good question. Very few practical examples in documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest thing is just to make the database connection object a module-level global variable. See this example [from the Motor documentation](http://motor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial-tornado.html#tornado-application-startup-sequence):

```
db = motor.motor_tornado.MotorClient().test_database

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/', MainHandler)
], db=db)

application.listen(8888)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

RequestHandlers could simply use the global variable directly. Also, passing the database as the db keyword argument to Application makes it available to request handlers in their "settings" dict:

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        db = self.settings['db']
```

This might make it easier to access the database object from RequestHandlers defined in other files.